# background image doesn't cover full width of element

Tags: html, css

On [this website](http://festivals.ie:8080/matts-gaff/), the menu has the following structure:

```
<ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-7">
        <a href="features/index.html">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-18">
        <a href="news-reviews/index.html">News &amp; Reviews</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-20">
        <a href="contact/index.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The `current_page_item` class changes the background of the currently selected menu item to black via the following rule:

```
.mainnav li.current_page_item a {
    background: url("images/bg_nav_hover.png") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
}
```

This works for the Home menu item, but for all others a small gap is left on the left-hand side of the selected menu item, highlighted by the yellow circle in the image below

[image]

I can't seem to figure out why this problem occurs for all menu items except Home.

Comment: You'd be interested in [this article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), given Jeff Rupert's answer (where I also linked the article).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<li>` tags are `display: inline-block;` and there are spaces between the tags.

Because your `<li>` tags are `inline-block`, they respect whitespace in the HTML, just like `inline` elements and text.

In the end, the background image *is* covering the background of the element correctly. Your best option to get rid of the spacing is to remove all whitespace between `</li>` and the next `<li>` tags.

As mentioned by @ajp15243 below, you can omit the closing tag, or use some wacky tricks to get the HTML to swallow up the whitespace.

Comment: Good catch, I've never experienced that before.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense once you think about it, but it took me multiple sites and attempts to figure out what was actually going on.

Comment: There are [multiple alternatives](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) to manage the space that isn't ignored with `inline-block`. Since these are `<li>`s, the closing `</li>` tag can be removed.

Comment: Good point. I find the lack of closing tag to be disconcerting, even though it's totally legit, so I didn't think of it.

Comment: @JeffRupert Agreed, I'm also not a fan of leaving off closing tags, but it's probably the most efficient way to do it with small `<li>`s.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `display:table-cell` for `.mainnav_wrapper .mainnav ul li` class.
then add a **padding** to center the menu items to your `ul` element:

```
.mainnav_wrapper ul {
    padding-left:192px;//this is especially for this project
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 960px;
}
```

and you are ready to go...